# using one AdMob AdRequest for multiple AdViews and intertitial?

Tags: android, performance, admob

I have an Android app which has a Banner and interstitial in every activity ( I have 3) and every banner & interstitial has its own AdRequest . But is it recommendable to use one AdRrequest for all of theme ? is that will make difference in admob network earnings ?
Could you help me ? and explain to me how can I maximize my eCPM ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Best to use individual ID's as that will give you a greater visibility as to which AD's are effective vs which ads are not.